# Issue using <layout> field in Multi window mode in android N

Tags: android, multi-window

I have added below code in my Application activity in AndroidManifest file. Its not taking effect of layout property.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MinimalSizeActivity"
        android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation">
        <layout
            android:defaultHeight="500dp"
            android:defaultWidth="750dp"
            android:gravity="top|end"
            android:minHeight="500dp"
            android:minWidth="500dp" />
    </activity>
```

Can any one explain How to test changes by adding layout property?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The `<layout>` tag's attributes aren't obeyed in multi-window mode. Have you figured out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that properties in .XML files. It may work!!

Comment: this property we have to add in manifest only. https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html